# System.InvalidCastException: 'Conversion from string "INSERT INTO Listing (ID_Listing," to type 'Double' is not valid.' In Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, windows-forms-designer

Im having this error pop up when running my app, i cant seem to find what causes the error, as I'm not even using any Double variables

```
 Private Sub btnCrearListing_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCrearListing.Click
    conexion.Open()
    Dim CrearListing As New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Listing (ID_Listing, precio, cantidad_item, ID_Usuario, ID_Item, Tipo_Listing) VALUES (" + ContadorListing + "," + Val(txtPrecio) + "," + Val(txtCantidad) + "," + Login.JugadorLogeado + "," + ItemListado + ",'" + cboTipoListing.Text + "')", conexion)
    ContadorListing = ContadorListing + 1
    conexion.Close()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're going to concatenate strings then use the concatenation operator (`&`), NOT the addition operator (`+`). If both operands are `String` objects then addition maps to concatenation. If the operands are different types though, one will need to be implicitly converted to the other type in order for the addition to be perfromed. In this case, the system is trying to implicitly convert the `String` to a `Double` in order to add it to the other number but it obviously fails because that `String` doesn't represent a number. If you use the concatenation operator then the system knows you want to concatenate, so it will convert the number to a `String`.

You really ought to have `Option Strict On`, which would catch bad code like this at compile time, rather than letting it slip through to run time. It won;t tell you how to fix it necessarily but it will at least tell you that there's something to fix. ALWAYS turn `Option Strict On` in your project properties and also in the VS options, so it will be `On` by default for all future projects. You can then turn it `On` at the file level on the rare occasions that you actually need it for specific code.

Having said all that, you shouldn't be building SQL code using string concatenation in the first place. ALWAYS use parameters as it avoids a number of issues. I won't go into specifics here, as that's beyond the scope of the question you actually asked, but you should [read this](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2009/08/using-parameters-in-adonet.html) and modify your code accordingly.